# How to calculate days between two dates in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I need to calculate days between a date I get from the database and the current date.

```
$upload_date = mysql_query("SELECT Date FROM Setting WHERE ID = $row[ID]");
$current_date = date("Y-m-d");
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Can you put what format the date is in?

Comment: They're both YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: `$daysDelta = floor((mktime() - strtotime($database['Date']) / 86400);` perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

```
select datediff(curdate(),'2011-03-01');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in PHP, then use the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) class:

```
$current = new DateTime($current_date);
$db_date = new DateTime($upload_date);
$days = $current->diff($db_date)->days;
```

Or the oldschool way:

```
$days = round((strtotime($current) - strtotime($db_date)) /24 /60 /60);
```

Answer (score 1):

form http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

```
SELECT DATEDIFF( CURDATE(), Date ) FROM ....
```

and I would not use `Date` as field name, consider to change this name

Answer (score 1):

Use **SELECT DATEDIFF('new_date', 'old_date');**

```
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2006-04-01','2006-04-01');
+-------------------------------------+
| DATEDIFF('2006-04-01','2006-04-01') |
+-------------------------------------+
|                                   0 |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2006-04-01','2007-04-01');
+-------------------------------------+
| DATEDIFF('2006-04-01','2007-04-01') |
+-------------------------------------+
|                                -365 |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2006-04-01','2005-04-01');
+-------------------------------------+
| DATEDIFF('2006-04-01','2005-04-01') |
+-------------------------------------+
|                                 365 |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

***DATEDIFF(expr,expr2)***

**DATEDIFF()** returns the number of days between the start date 
expr and the end date expr2. expr and expr2 are date or 
date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values 
are used in the calculation.

```
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('1997-12-31 23:59:59','1997-12-30');
    -> 1
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('1997-11-30 23:59:59','1997-12-31');
    -> -31
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this format http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and it will do it for you

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in a simple way as below,

```
$current_date = date("Y-m-d");          // Current date
$db_date = date("Y-m-d");               // Date from your database
$diff = abs(strtotime($current_date) - strtotime($db_date));
$total_days = floor ($diff /  (60*60*24));
```